# Hide div depending on horizontal browserviewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter's Bootstrap 2 with fluid-layout (responsive design) and want to hide a div-box if the browser's horizontal size is smaller than 800px.

How can i make it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can apply a custom class to the element you wish to hide and add a `display:none` property to it to hide it inside a `@media` query that targets the width of your choice, like so:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .hidden-800 {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Just make sure to place the `@media` query way down at the end of your custom stylesheet.

Comment: @JoonKiChoi I'm glad :) if the answer i posted satisfied your question please mark it as such by ticking the checkmark next to my answer, that way we can put closure to this question and it can help future users.